# Evaluating $f + g$, $f - g$, $fg$, $f/g$, and $g \circ f$ at a point given graphs of $f$ and $g$

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

A picture of the problem is here: https://gyazo.com/7b4dd032fbb0cff5f5f528bb0928987f

I'm confused on how to do this, the answer needs to be an exact number. My friend ran me through how to do the first one but I'm still very confused on the method.

Another type of problem I'm very confused on is here: https://gyazo.com/7d63795b0dee0a3a35fed4980cc0d6ba

If anyone could be kind enough, please let me know the method to solve these as I don't know.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you know how to find the values of $f(-1)$ and $g(-1)$ in the first graph and $f(0)$ in the second? Or does that need explained, too?

Comment: Could you explain that too? I think I know the basics but I'd like to get this concept down.

Comment: Please upload the pictures in your post. If the links go dead, then your question will lose its usefulness for others. It also saves time for the people who want to answer.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a new account, I don't have enough "reputation to upload a picture yet.

Answer (score 0):

The graph of $f$ is all the points $(x, y)$ where $y = f(x)$. So to find the value of $f(-1)$, look for $-1$ on the $x$-axis. Follow it straight up (or down for some functions, but not for this one) until you arrive at the graph of $f$. Then head across horizontally until you get to the $y$-axis to find the value of $y = f(-1)$. That tells you what $f(-1)$ is. Do the same thing for $g(-1)$.

Then $$(f + g)(-1) = f(-1) + g(-1)$$
$$(f - g)(-1) = f(-1) - g(-1)$$
$$(fg)(-1) = f(-1) \cdot g(-1)$$
$$\left (\frac f g \right)(-1) = \frac{f(-1)}{g(-1)}$$

For the 2nd problem, $(g \circ f)(0) = g( f(0))$ So find $f(0)$ as above. Whatever that value is, find the value of $g(x)$ when $x = f(0)$. That is your answer.

Comment: So by using this method then, the answer to (f - g)(-1) would be -3? I'm not sure if I did that correctly because the software is telling me that is the incorrect answer. If I did this incorrectly (Which is the probable cause) I'll just write down what I did following your instructions. Starting at -1 on the X axis I went up to (-1,1) then went to the right 1 to reach (1,1) which would then tell me that f(-1) = 1. I then did the same for the graph of g(x) to get an answer of g(-1) = 4, I subtracted the two which would be (f - g) or (1 - 4) to give me the answer of -3.

Comment: Please do. $(f-g)(-1) = -3$.

Comment: I did it correctly now with your steps, I messed up in the simplest way. I thank you so much for that first problem, I now know how to solve it.

Comment: If it's not a nuisance, could you possibly run me through the second problem. I really do not want to get this wrong as there are a couple problems of that nature and these online Homeworks count for a decent portion of our grade.

Comment: What is $f(0)$ in the second graph?

Comment: Actually, I apologize if following me is confusing. I figured out the first problem, the final answer for (g(f)(0)) = 3. I tried using the same method for the next problem which is https://gyazo.com/352c2c5d543b972ea94f41b7f3c6e6bd but I'm failing to come up with a proper answer. From what I've done the answer SHOULD be 5 but it's telling me that is incorrect.

Comment: You are doing $g \circ f$, but this problem is asking for $f \circ g$.

Comment: For the second problem,  (f∘g)(4) is the one I'm having issues with, the (g∘f)(0) problem I was able to do with your method, the answer is 3. I'm having trouble coming to an answer though with the second problem which is  (f∘g)(4) using the graph https://gyazo.com/74328a79253756522ae40ee99e5be666

Comment: And what I am telling you is that the reason it went wrong for you is that you calculated $(g\circ f)(4)$ instead of $(f\circ g)(4)$ like it asked.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, my stupidity got the best of me, the correct answer is 0 for the second question. Thank you so much for not getting angry at my absurdness, I certainly would have.

Comment: I've been there before. We all make those mistakes. It took me a minute or two to spot the problem myself. But from experience, I know where to look when things go wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much, your help has brought this "homework" from a 65% to a 96% (I had already gotten some wrong).